# Wordpress Form Submission Redirecting to ?=s

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In a Wordpress site, I have a front end form whose action attribute is https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php and is supposed to use a function that I have set in the functions.php file. All works ok for users logged in who are Administrators but if a user is logged in as anything else, the form goes directly to https://example.com/?=s.

Has anyone else experienced this?

What other information would you need to assist with this?

Thanks

Comment: Share the code to provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please.

Comment: Seems like this would fit better on [wordpress.se]